# Adding rollover styles to slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

Hi I've a simple JavaScript slideshow, I was wondering how could add slideshow effects like fade in and fade out on the slideshow. This is the slideshow code:

```
var i, imgs, pic;

function rotate()
{
  pic.src = imgs[i] ;
  (i === (imgs.length -1) ) ? i=0 : i++ ;
  setTimeout( rotate, 5000 ); 
}

function init()
{
  pic = document.getElementById("pic");

  imgs = [ "/beta/images/img1.jpg", "/beta/images/img2.jpg", "/beta/images/img3.jpg", "/beta/images/img4.jpg" ] ;

  var preload= new Array();
  for( i=0; i< imgs.length; i++ )
  {
    preload[ i ] = new Image();
    preload[ i ].src = imgs[ i ];
  }

  i=0;

  rotate();
}
onload=init;
```

I tried changing my `rotate()` to this:

```
function rotate()
{
  pic.src = imgs[i] ;
  (i === (imgs.length -1) ) ? i=0 : i++ ;
  setInterval( rotate, 5000 ); 
   $("#pic").fadeIn().show(10000).fadeOut();
}
```

and it started messing up

Comment: You'll need to give it a try and ask for help with your code.

Comment: @isherwood I did I tried adding some fading in effects as well as easing and the like but unfortunately it just messed up my code and the images stopped sliding

Comment: Show. Your. Code. :-) This isn't FreeFreelancer.com. (Hmm... is that a thing?)

Comment: @isherwood I've edited it with the code which was messing the slideshow up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/ukNmT/

I created a simple slide show with fading effect using jQuery.

**HTML Code**

```
<div id='items'>
    <div class='item first'>Item 1</div>
    <div class='item'>Item 2</div>
    <div class='item'>Item 3</div>
    <div class='item'>Item 4</div>
    <div class='item'>Item 5</div>
</div>
<ul id='controls'>
    <li id='prev'>Prev</li>
    <li id='play'>Play</li>
    <li id='pause'>Pause</li>
    <li id='next'>Next</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS Code**

```
#items {
    position : relative;
    width : 400px;
    height : 200px;
    top : 20px;
    left : 20px;
}
.item {
    position : absolute;
    background-color : #eee;
    border : 1px solid #ccc;
    width : 398px;
    height : 198px;
    display :none;
    text-align : center;
    font-size : 72px;
}
.first{
    display : block;
}
#controls {
    margin-top : 30px;
}
li {
    display : inline-block;
    padding : 5px;
    border : 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color : #eee;
    cursor : pointer;
}
#play {
    display : none;
}
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
//To store timeout id
var timeoutId;

var slideImage = function( step ) {

    if ( step == undefined ) step = 1;

    //Clear timeout if any
    clearTimeout ( timeoutId );

    //Get current image's index
    var indx = $('.item:visible').index('.item');

    //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
    if ( step != 0 ) {
       //Fadeout this item
       $('.item:visible').fadeOut();
    }

    //Increment for next item
    indx = indx + step ;

    //Check bounds for next item
    if ( indx >= $('.item').length ) {
        indx = 0;
    } else if ( indx < 0 ) {
        indx = $('.item').length - 1;
    }

    //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
    if ( step != 0 ) {
       //Fadein next item
       $('.item:eq(' + indx + ')').fadeIn();
    }

    //Set Itmeout
    timeoutId = setTimeout ( slideImage, 5000 );
};

//Start sliding
slideImage(0);

//When clicked on prev
$('#prev').click(function() {

    //slideImage with step = -1
    slideImage ( -1 );   
});

//When clicked on next
$('#next').click(function() {

     //slideImage with step = 1
     slideImage ( 1 );
});

//When clicked on Pause
$('#pause').click(function() {

   //Clear timeout
   clearTimeout ( timeoutId );    

    //Hide Pause and show Play
    $(this).hide();
    $('#play').show();
});

//When clicked on Play
$('#play').click(function() {

   //Start slide image
   slideImage(0);

   //Hide Play and show Pause
   $(this).hide();
   $('#pause').show();    
});
```

Comment: Working in Jsfiddle but not working in my code. When I look at the code in developer tools menu on my browser it says:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined test.html:54
slideImage test.html:54
(anonymous function)

Comment: Include jQuery library in your code. I used it for better coding.

Comment: I included the jQuery library but still no luck

Comment: Is it possible to see your code? It will help me to understand the issue properly.